# Can't close modal using closeIcon on semantic-ui-react

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react

I'm using semantic ui's modal and they have a property called `closeIcon` that suppose to close the modal... But it doesn't close. I'm not sure but maybe because the modal's visibility is based on my state that's why their wrapper won't work?

Can I pass a function to the `closeIcon` prop instead?

Comment: Can you show your related code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `closeIcon` takes `true` or `false` as an option and that is for displaying that close button and not actually closing the modal. There's another property namely `open` which actually closes the modal. What you need to do is pass `true` to `closeIcon` property and pass a function to `onClose` property in which you change the `open` state to false.

Comment: You can have a look at this: https://react.semantic-ui.com/modules/modal for reference.